# How can I remove the white box on the IOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ios-simulator

I am making a game with Ionic/Angular. When I serve on the web or any android device there is no problem. But when I tried on the IOS simulator there is a white box on the center of the screen like the image below. I tried with multiple simulators (iPhone 8/11/12 pro etc.)

[image]

This box appears on every page and if there is something underneath I can not click.
I tried to set z-index of elements 2147483647 (which is the max value for z-index apperently) still this box on top of the all elements. When I inspect with the safari dev tools, its not in the code, I can’t click with the aim tool on safari. Currently, I am not able to try with a real device. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you share your screen code?

Comment: @LouaySleman what do you mean by screen code?

Comment: your HTML code for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue for me was because of the `cordova-lottie-splashscreen` plugin. I removed that and problem solved. Hope it helps

Comment: I remember that I installed that plugin probably that was the issue thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new ionic app and copied/pasted it step by step to figure out at what point this box appears. It didn’t appear. If you face an issue similar to this try re-create your project.

Comment: We got the same issue, what was it that caused the white block?

Comment: If you installed the `cordova-lottie-splashscreen` pluging try to uninstall it like @Cliffordwh suggested.